# In flow how to accept a heterogeneous array, and return that array

Tags: javascript, generics, casting, flowtype, heterogeneous-array

When I have a function which accepts an array of a generic type and return a transformed array, I could write:

```
function myfun<T>(input: Array<T>): Array<T> {}
```

However this fails if the array is of heterogeneous type, since T is then different over the array. Now since I know that T will always be a subtype of a certain base: `BaseTy` and during the function I only use functions from/that operate on the base type, I could write:

```
function myfun(input: Array<BaseTy>): Array<BaseTy> {}
```

However this has the problem that the actual type is "lost" and the array is thus no longer a heterogeneous array of the derived type.

Can this be fixed in flow without resorting to unsafe typecasts or `any`?

Comment: Why not something like `function myfun(input: Array<A extends BaseType>): Array<A extends BaseType> {}`? As shown in the examples here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Comment: @TheChetan I'm using flowtype, not typescript. But besides that point: it requires me to manually downcast back to the derived type: creating copies I should not have to make. (I do not wish to let flow write me different code than I previously did).

Comment: Can you provide more context on the function you are trying to write? At first glance, you might be able to solve the problem by using `$ReadOnlyArray`, but I need more details to know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use a [bounded generic](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/#toc-generic-types-act-as-bounds) to specify the minimum type that can be accepted, while also allowing the function to return a more specific type:

```
function myfun<T: BaseTy>(input: Array<T>): Array<T> {
    // whatever you want to do here
    return input
}
```

Full code example:

```
type BaseType = {
    base: 'whatever'
}
type TypeA = BaseType & { a: 'Foo' }
type TypeB = BaseType & { b: 'Bar' }
type TypeC = BaseType & { c: 'Baz' }

function myfun<T: BaseType>(input: Array<T>): Array<T> {
    return input
}

const a = {
  base: 'whatever',
  a: 'Foo'
}

const b = {
  base: 'whatever',
  b: 'Bar'
}

const c = {
  base: 'whatever',
  c: 'Baz'
}


const aAndBs: Array<TypeA | TypeB> = [a, b]
const aAndCs: Array<TypeA | TypeC> = [a, c]

// Correct
const xs1: Array<TypeA | TypeB> = myfun(aAndBs)

// Error - It's actually returning Array<TypeA | TypeC>
const xs2: Array<TypeA | TypeB> = myfun(aAndCs)
```

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAQghgZwgFXNAvFA3gKAJABGiEAXFAOQDuAFnMBAG4QBO5OAvjjqJFKpAEEomeEn7QAZNihwy5AGIB7ReSice0cTGGxi4qFKxQCc+KzXc0fNAGEdolFcNQAxqbgAvVZxwAzAK4Adi7AAJaKgVAAtiABgQA8yGQO4gB8ABShgWD+wGQCzMxwIImpAJT5hcWl2PjMEMD+zJFZOcAcXC4RCMAyOrhQxsRyNHSMLOQANDiDshRKKh04XYE9xv0zQ0gjtPRMrNODJhRmbD4ray4bR8MUo3sTh67uXkvL3b1wAoEAJjAIlSKJXEQgAPtZIDBUjoANpwSbGAC671Wn2+PxsAKgBSBiTQYIhEBs0MwcIRLmROAA9FSoDZFIUICEUWsAB4IACMgOqIKg4K0JOisSC6S+v3+ZWptIAooUGSzeuyAEzc4H4vmEqE6GJxUXozGSoA))

Like Jordan said, you may want to change the type of the input array to `$ReadOnlyArray` if you run into trouble with [variance](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/variance/):

```
function myfun<T: BaseType>(input: $ReadOnlyArray<T>): $ReadOnlyArray<T> {
    return input
}
```